# How to send additional data to firebase push notification

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was able to send push notifications to both Ios/Android using php and curl.Right now i want to update the code to send additional parameters such as user_id,name.So i can get these information on my frontend side.But i don't know how to pass these data.Can anyone please help me.

```
function sendPushNotification($token,$push_notification_title=null,$push_notification_body=null){

$url = env('FIREBASE_URL');
$serverKey = env('FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY');
$title = $push_notification_title??"New Physician Review";
$body = $push_notification_body??"Your case has been reviewed";

$notification = array('title' => $title, 'text' => $body, 'body' => $body, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1');
$arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification, 'priority' => 'high', 'data' => $notification, 'content_available' => true);

$json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: key=' . $serverKey;


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

return $response;
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to include additional information in your message, you can add a `data` array. This `data` array is similar to the `notification` array you already have, but it is **not** handled by the system and simply passed to your application code.

So something like this:

```
$notification = array('title' => $title, 'text' => $body, 'body' => $body, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1');
$data = array('user_id' => 'youruserid', 'name' => 'yohan'); //  new array
$arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification, 
                     'priority' => 'high', 'data' => $data, 'content_available' => true);
                                                    //  use it here
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.This solution worked